# Memory allocation failed: growing buffer on PHP, SoapClient

Tags: php, memory, soap, soap-client

I am running SOAP client from php and laravel to get a 2mb xml from magento. Sometimes the call succeeds, but mostly it fails with this message:

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

SoapClient::__call(): Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
```

Any ideas how to fix that?
memory_limit in php.ini is set to 1024M

Comment: setting this configuration in php.ini does not mean that 1024 will be exclusively allocated for PHP, but the maximum that php script may consume. try to monitore your server when you are doing this operation. Total Free memory, used memory for each process, and used memory by PHP. you can use sysinternal tools

Comment: 1 GB free out of 2 GB ram when this process is running. This is very strange...

Comment: Funny thing that, when I restart apache, the process runs the first time successfully, and the next time it fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the server was running out of ram. I increased ram from 2GB to 4GB and everything worked smoothly

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with SoapClient, I've managed to fix the issue by setting "soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=0" i.e. disabling SOAP caching in php.ini.

Comment: This is what worked for me.  I attempted to double the memory I was allowing my script to use as the OP stated they did, but it didn't work until I turned off caching.